# Can I trust password manager software?

Tags: windows-7, security, password-management

I'm considering downloading a password manager so that I don't keep forgetting my passwords.
The problem is, how do I know that the password manager itself is both hackproof and trustworthy, i.e. no back doors built in by unscrupulous developers?
Can you recommend any such password manager software?

Comment: This question is really broad. There are tons of open source password managers that exist. You certainly can trust those. Software recomendations are not on topic here at Superuser. So you understand there are multiple reasons i issued a downvote. Its not on topic since its asking for a software recomendation, your asking can you trust a password manager instead of should I ( even that is still a primarily opinion-based answer ), and the question is extremely broad.

Comment: @Ramhound, the main thrust of the question is how to know whether password manager software is trustworthy.  The recommendation is peripheral.  Why is the question OT?

Comment: If you want to convince yourself, you'll have to audit the entirety of the source code yourself. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

[Keepass](http://keepass.info/) is open source and therefore everyone with needed skills can "audit" it and proove it (relatively) safe (relatively because never say never).

That's what i personally use, it's very efficient and has plenty of plugins for browsers, backup, sync, etc.

IMHO, you can trust most of opensource well known software like Keepass. If you want to trust a 3rd party company like LastPass ou 1password, your passwords should be salted with a key on the client and it should be fine, but once again you'll never know...

Answer (score 1):

When it comes down to it, nothing online is completely safe. Look at recent news about leaked user information and you'll understand big or small, someone somewhere will find a loophole. I suppose it's one of those things you'll need decide if you want to take a risk on.